# Keeping track of a position in a 2D Array

Tags: java

I am currently keeping track of a position in a 2D Array using Point

For example:

```
Item[][] listOfItems = new Item[3][3];
//some logic here to determine the best item
Point tempBest = new Point(2,2);
```

Is there a better way of doing this as obviously a point refers to two double coordinates however it will only ever be a combination of 2 integers since it refers to an array instead of a point in space.

Comment: Asking for better code should goes to CodeReview. Your code is nice, there is no "better" solution as the problem is simple, a simple array of 2 boxes would be ok too

Comment: @azro where is code review sorry

Comment: @Alex https://codereview.stackexchange.com/